# vhdl-mode key binding not working

Tags: key-bindings

I want to use the **vhdl-mode** in Emacs. I can use the templates when working with the meta key like:

`M-x vhdl-template-process`

If i want to use the corresponding key binding like:

`C-c C-t P`

it won't work.

I am new to Emacs, so it might be kind of a general problem working with some package.

Comment: Are you in a buffer that's in `vhdl-mode`?

Comment: Provide a simple, step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, saying what you do and what you see at each step and what you expect/want to see instead. Start from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: Yes, when opening the .vhd file it should automatically start vhdl-mode. The syntax is highlited correctly which indicates vhdl-mode is on, and when entering the commands using meta key and string commands they work properly, just the key binding doesn't work. 1. open emcas from terminal 2. open vhd file in folder (syntax is recognized correctly) 3. try command stated in question using key bindings 4. doesn't recognize command 5. using meta-key and string command 6. does what it is supposed to do, creates template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the definition of function `vhdl-template-map-init`. You can use <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `vhdl-template-map-init` <kbd>RET</kbd> and klick on the function name to follow the link to the source or you can just use [this web link to a git repro on repo.or.cz](http://repo.or.cz/emacs.git/blob/HEAD:/lisp/progmodes/vhdl-mode.el#l2717). There you see the keybindings within `vhdl-template-map`. Those bindings are active after pressing <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-t</kbd>.

Examples:

1. `(define-key vhdl-template-map "Pd" 'vhdl-template-package-decl)`
2. `(define-key vhdl-template-map "Pb" 'vhdl-template-package-body)`.

The letters in the strings indicate the keys you have to type after <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-t</kbd>. So it looks like you are missing `d` (standing for `decl`) or `b` (standing for `body`) after `P` (standing for `package`).

Comment: Dear Tobias, I tried to do what you supposed to, I don't seem to have the function definition file  vhdl-template-map-init, at least I would't find one searching as root. I suppose that is the source of my issue. How do I correctly install it, what is the correct destination such that emacs will find the files?

Comment: @Marin `vhdl-template-map-init` is part [of the official repro](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/c70d22f70b77b053d01c7380122d166ecb728610/lisp/progmodes/vhdl-mode.el#L2673) since [2013](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blame/c70d22f70b77b053d01c7380122d166ecb728610/lisp/progmodes/vhdl-mode.el#L2673). Note that `vhdl-template-map-init` is not autoloaded. That means you need to load `vhdl-mode.el` before calling `C-h f vhdl-template-map-init RET`. You can do that with `M-x load-library RET vhdl-mode RET`. Furthermore, you need the lisp sources and not just the compiled libs.